# Law of Total Covariance with Potential Outcomes

Tags: covariance, causality

I'm attempting to derive the covariance between the sample mean for the treatment and control arm of a completely randomized experiment where the units in the experiment, $n$, are a random sample from a larger, but not infinite, population $N$.

Define $A = \frac{1}{n_t} \sum_{i = 1}^{N} y_{i, t} \cdot T_i$ and $B = \frac{1}{n_c} \sum_{i = 1}^{N} y_{i, c} \cdot C_i$.

Following the potential outcomes framework, $y_{i, t}$ and $y_{i, c}$ are constant and represent potential outcomes for unit $i$ under treatment and control respectively. $T_i$ and $C_i$ are random indicator variables determining assignment to treatment ($T_i = 1, C_i = 0$) and control ($T_i = 0, C_i = 1$).

Let $R$ be an indicator variable where $R = 1$ if $T_i + C_i = 1$ and otherwise $0$ and define $n = \sum^N_{i = 1} R_i$. Furthermore, $n_t = \sum^N_{i = 1} T_i$ and $n_c = \sum^N_{i = 1} C_i$.

Where $n, n_t, n_c$ are fixed and $n > N$, I want to derive $Cov(A, B)$ by utilizing the law of total covariance.

$$
Cov(A, B) = \mathbb{E}(Cov(A, B \mid R)) + Cov \left( \mathbb{E}(A \mid R), \mathbb{E}(B \mid R) \right)
$$
Because $R$ is discrete, we can expand the first term as follows

$$
\mathbb{E}(Cov(A, B \mid R))  =   \mathbb{E}(Cov(A, B \mid R = 0)) \cdot \mathbb{P}(R = 0) + \mathbb{E}(Cov(A, B \mid R = 1)) \cdot \mathbb{P}(R = 1)\\
$$
$Cov(A, B \mid R = 0) = 0$ because when $R = 0$ then $T, C = 0$ and $A, B$ are fixed. Furthermore, it can be shown that $Cov(A, B \mid R = 1) = - \frac{S_{A, B}}{n}$ where $S_{A, B} = \frac{1}{N -1} \sum^N_{i = 1} (y_{i, T} - \bar{y_T})(y_{i,C} - \bar{y_C})$. We also have that $\mathbb{P}(R = 1) = \frac{n}{N}$. This gives us

$$
\mathbb{E}(Cov(A, B \mid R)) = \mathbb{E}(- \frac{S_{A, B}}{n}) \cdot \frac{n}{N} = - \frac{\sigma _{A, B}}{N}
$$
How do I derive the second term?

$$
\begin{aligned}
&Cov \left( \mathbb{E}(A \mid R), \mathbb{E}(B \mid R) \right) \\
&= \mathbb{E} \left[\mathbb{E}(A \mid R) \mathbb{E}(B \mid R)  \right] - \mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(A \mid R)) \cdot \mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(B \mid R)) \\
&= \mathbb{E} \left[\mathbb{E}(A \mid R) \mathbb{E}(B \mid R)  \right] - \mu_T \cdot \mu_C \\
\end{aligned}
$$

I recognize that $\mathbb{E}(A \mid R)$, etc. are functions but I'm not sure how to proceed further.

This question is similar to several questions on applications of the law of total covariance, including this [one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/244711/how-to-implement-law-of-total-covariance) but looking at this answer was not enough for me to figure this out.

Comment: What are $S_{j, c}$, $S_{A, B}$, and $\sigma_{A, B}$?

Comment: @DF The first was a typo. I've added the definition for the $S_{A, B}$.

Comment: I still don't get your framework, what is $\bar{y}_{T}$? Is it $A$? What is sigma? Is $n$ random or not? It seems to be random as a sum of random indicators, but then in your expression of $E(Cov(A, B|R))$ the RHS is random while the LHS is not...

Comment: @DF $n$ is fixed, i.e. we want to conduct a randomize experiment involve $n$ units from the population $N$. We also fix the number to include in the control and treatment arm, $n_t, n_c$. $E(A) = \mu_T$ but $\bar{y_T}$ would be the mean only for those units in the experiment so generally $\bar{y_T} \neq E(A)$.

Comment: How come the sum of random indicators is fixed? Or all this expecations/probabilities are conditional on $n, n_t, n_c$?

Comment: @DF which random indicators? $n, n_t, n_c$ are all fixed because we've determined to conduct a randomized experiment with $n$ units with $n_t$ units in the treatment arm and $n_c$ units in the control arm.

Comment: $n_t = \sum_{i=1}^N T_i$ where $T_i$ is as you wrote "random indicator variable" which implies that $n_t$ is random. Unless as I said all the expectations and probabilities are conditional on $n, n_t, n_c$

Comment: @DF I understand your question now. $T_i$ is random but $n_t$ is not because the number of units assigned to treatment, $n_t$, is fixed but whether unit $i$ is assigned to treatment ($T_i = 1 v. T_i = 0$) is random. I've edited the post to make this clear.

Comment: What you're saying doesn't make any sense to me. Sum of random variables is in general random, period. If $T_i$ is random for all i then $n_t$ is random. You cannot "fix" the number of realization of a random variable.

Comment: @DF that would be the case if you randomizing by flipping coins. You'd have a Bernouli indicator variable and $n_t$ would be a random variable (and we won't have to worry about covariance). I'm interested in the more common case where you're essentially drawing names without replacement, so the indicator variable follows a hypergeometric distribution. You determine that the first $n_t$ names you draw will be assigned to the treatment arm.

Comment: So the experiment looks as follows: out of N different units you randomly draw $n_t$ names without replacements, and observe $y_{i, t}$ for those units, then you draw another $n_c$ names out of the remaining $N-n_t$ units without replacement and observe $y_{i, c}$ for those units?

Comment: @DT Precisely, and what you're trying to estimate is the difference in $y_t$ and $y_c$ for the whole population. In the case that $n = N$ you have the variance derived by Neyman but the case here where $n < N$ is different.